# How can I set the output feature type name dynamically?

Tags: fme-form

How can I set the output feature type name so that it consists of a constant part and a variable part, such as "Circle_205", where the number part could be different each time?

When using a fanout, this is easy to set, but without a fanout, I do not know how to do this, unfortunately.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use a fanout?

Comment: Good question! No, there is not any special reason for that, but I was wondering how to do this without using fanout.

Comment: But how to set prefix or suffix fanout to an attribute value? I tried @Value(att_name) but it is not correct!

Comment: Did you see my [second link](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/String-Concatenator)?

Comment: Yes, i tried, but it is different with FME2012 ?!:(

Comment: I tried to modify my old wb, change from static to dynamic schema, but it does not work! It seems like everything should be done from begin.

Comment: What version of FME are you using? You could also use a [StringConcatenator](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/Default.htm#transformers/stringconcatenator.htm) transformer instead. As for the other problems you are having I am not sure I can help there.

Comment: I am using FME2012, build 12212. I tried with StringConcate. The problem is if I generate new workspace as dynamic, on the output writer is not enabled Dynamic Properties, and I cannot change it.

Comment: Do you have any readers in your workspace? What does your writer Feature Type Properties window look like?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5883/discussion-between-z77-and-blah238)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use a [dynamic schema](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/FAQ/Q-A-What-is-a-Dynamic-Schema) on your writer, e.g. set the feature type name to the attribute you create, for example, by [concatenating](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/String-Concatenator) the constant with the variable part.

This post on the [FME Evangelist blog](http://evangelism.safe.com/) should get you going: [FME Evangelist: The Dynamic Duo](http://evangelism.safe.com/fmeevangelist31/)

Comment: I have a dynamic feature name but how do I then remove the name so it does not show up in the output table as rows?

Comment: Hi @blah238, just to inform you. the links are dead by now